# How to get just the time zone name from Intl.DateTimeFormat?

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

I am trying to generate a date object and then save the various formatted parts to variables. All it working except that I cannot seem to only generate/format the time zone name on its own.

The following code will produce `3/20/2024, EDT` but I only want `EDT` to be produced.

```js
const timeZoneFormatter1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
  timeZoneName: "short",
  timeZone: "America/New_York",
});
console.log(timeZoneFormatter1.format(now));
```

What options am I missing? How do I get it to omit the date information and only produce the time zone name?

I suppose I could just get it manually with `'3/20/2024, EDT'.split(',')[1].trim()` but that feels very hacky to me.

Here's a working demo of my attempts

```js
const now = new Date();
const locale = "en-US";
const timeZone = "America/New_York"; //always use HQ local time zone

const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
  weekday: "short",
  month: "short",
  day: "numeric",
  timeZone,
});
console.log('Date:', dateFormatter.format(now));

const timeFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric",
  timeZone,
});
console.log('Time:', timeFormatter.format(now));

const timeZoneFormatter1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
  timeZoneName: "short",
  timeZone,
});
console.log('TimeZone attempt #1:', timeZoneFormatter1.format(now));

const timeZoneFormatter2 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
  month: undefined,
  day: undefined,
  year: undefined,
  timeZoneName: "short",
  timeZone,
});
console.log('TimeZone attempt #2:', timeZoneFormatter2.format(now));

const timeZoneFormatter3 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
  timeZoneName: "short",
  timeZone,
});
console.log('TimeZone attempt #3 (hacky):', timeZoneFormatter2.format(now).split(',')[1].trim());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateTimeFormat.formatToParts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) and use the value of the `timeZoneName` part.

This is much less hacky than doing any string manipulation.

```js
const now = new Date();
const locale = "en-US";
const timeZone = "America/New_York"; //always use HQ local time zone

const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
  weekday: "short",
  month: "short",
  day: "numeric",
  timeZone,
});
console.log('Date:', dateFormatter.format(now));

const timeFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric",
  timeZone,
});
console.log('Time:', timeFormatter.format(now));

const timeZoneFormatter1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
  timeZoneName: "short",
  timeZone,
});

const parts = timeZoneFormatter1.formatToParts(now);
console.log('parts:', parts);

const tzName = parts.find(x => x.type === 'timeZoneName').value;
console.log('timeZoneName:', tzName);
```

Answer (score -2):

he Intl.DateTimeFormat constructor does not directly support formatting only the time zone name without including other date or time components.

However, you can achieve this by formatting a fixed date that only includes the time zone information and then extracting the time zone name from it.

[Working Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGIHcYF44FMkBECGU0AoBKAbgChRJYAbEYbKtFGAIjTAFoBVAZWbIugwoASwC2aAFrhGqZgEFxAJ2F0A9ADkMAfQCaIRQGs%20MVaphyqCbAE8IMAK4RGACQCKMGnSpCxjAF7SpKSmMABi%20qK4MNgwAGbCAB5oACYwybiM%20JxgiTBoAA60ABaEQiAwAOZosOBU1kJFjCLiMAFgjGDY4uTggs2S0uGKkVB4ikztSACSYFBUAHQ4eAAqvkMj%20J70aAA0MADepDA%204lLt6l1oAFwsEEX6UMw7RzD39oo3zGD2SipPL6JhN88J9vr9gP9jk4KMlQT80MoIc9jm9FABGABMN1i9CcexCnCcMAxABZ2Ki4hEolBytgAG4gYSpLoAI2EFXswig1he-TOu1IAF8SEEQusojF4klUuk8DAsjkEnlCsASmVKtUYLV6lBGid-NI4JcepR9fyLi1UHzBlTRgj5rFbfgAAyEeYQfJULn4ADkMB9hAA2miALrEExmACiCSgimwwBEYAqDSavlahs63RNEBADHmNAqvtWLX5Vx9e2t50uIqAA)

```
const now = new Date();
const locale = "en-US";
const timeZone = "America/New_York"; // Always use HQ local time zone

// Format a fixed date (Unix epoch) to get only the time zone name
const timeZoneFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
  timeZoneName: "short",
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric",
  hour12: false, // Use 24-hour format to avoid ambiguity
  timeZone,
});

// Format a fixed date (Unix epoch) to get only the time zone name
const timeZoneName = timeZoneFormatter.format(0).split(' ')[1]; // Extracting the time zone name

console.log('Time Zone:', timeZoneName);
```

Comment: This is basically what I am already showing in my question for the "hacky" way that I do not want to do. The only difference is that I split on a comma character and you are splitting on a space character.